# What's Outlook 2016 form for forwarded meeting?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016, email-filter

I'm creating rules to sort email, but I can't figure out what form to use to catch all those stating my meetings have been forwarded. I can find Accept, Decline, etc, under Application Forms, but one alludes me is forwarded meeting. Anyone knows how I can accomplish this? I've tried a few that sounds like they might me the one (like "Sharing Request"), but none works.

Preferably, it should not be handled by the local computer ("client-only") as I use mobile daily.

(I *can* do a "contains X in subject", but since it only covers a specific language, I'd have to have more than I'd like.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is not a direct rule for this. Since you will receive a message which tell you that your meeting has been forwarded when your meeting was forwarded. It is suggested to set a rule using the keywords "Your meeting was forwarded" in the body.

Comment: So there's no Application Form (that can be used for other scenarios, as mentioned above, non-language specifically)? Can I create a Personal Form, or something else?

Comment: You may try to find some codeor VBA macro to achieve your purpose.